# Should controller tests include authentification?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, spring-boot-test

In my project I am currently refactoring a bunch of controller tests, and I came across the question whether I should include authentification in my test-scope or not.

Right now I am testing my controllers in a very limited scope. I test:

- Status codes
- Requests
- Responses
- Controller business logic
- Serialisation/Deserialisation

Personally I think, that authentification should NOT be part of those tests, but there are others in my project that disagree. It mostly is a historical issue, since authentification used to be part of those tests in my project since forever.

Are there any definitive suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want automated test that run without authentication (unit test), and also have test that includes authentication (integration test (or whatever you want to call them)). You should aim to have lots of unit test, and they should be able to execute in isolation (really fast), since they are the shortest development loop you have. Then you want to run your integration test, say on you build server during a deploy in order to catch regression bugs and such. You should aim to have (much) less integration tests than unit tests...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The line between unit tests and integration tests is fleeting, though, right? A controller test with @AutoConfigureMockMvc has a limited scope, but it kinda is an integrationtest, because integration with the spring framework for creation of the web layer is a relevant part of the test. Would you agree?